# When referring to dates, which form is correct? "on the 5th of November" or "on the 5th November"?

Tags: grammar

I was discussing this at work with a colleague today, which form (or both) is grammatically correct when referring to dates?

"on the 5th of November"

vs

"on the 5th November"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"on the 5th of November" is practically just removing the word day from the reference. As in "on the 5th (day) of November." It is used everywhere and even though it could be understood a few different ways it is the most correct.

"on the 5th November" seems to me to more be dependent on the month and if not year. As in "it's my baby's 5th November" as in, the child is experiencing November for the 5th separate time.

In this sense I wouldn't ever use the latter reference. It sounds wrong, feels wrong and is grammatically incorrect. An educated reader could understand "the fifth of November", I'd be abashed if someone wanted to meet me on "the fifth November".

TL;DR Safest choice would be "on the 5th day of November" but the first is definitely the much better option.

Comment: Who says on the 5th day of November unless they are writing a Gothic novel and suchlike? :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "on the 5th of November," because saying "on the 5th November" It makes it sound like you are talking about the 5th November, as in 5 years later.

You need the proposition [of] to make the sentence work.

Answer (score 0):

Either "the 5th of November" or "November 5th".  "On the 5th November" is confusing at best and not at all idiomatic.